# how to get from address in outlook when multiple mailboxes are configured using add-in express

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, addin-express

is there way to get 'from' address(sender) form outlook when multiple mailboxes are configured using add-in express.

i want to capture sender address before sending the mail inside item_send event .
following property always give default email address not the selected one.

```
mail.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress
```

[image]

I am using outlook 2016 64 bit version

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use the `Namespace.Accounts` collection and read the`Account.SmtpAddress` property.